# Conda fails to set up paths when activating an environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am using miniconda 4.5.1 on 4.13.0-37-generic GNU/Linux
I am also using tmux, if that's useful.

When I activate my environment by running `source activate ___`
conda fails to set up the paths, meaning my `python` and `pip` commands are still mapped to the conda regular (or whatever the name is) python commands, not those from my environment. I get the `(env-name)` tag before my terminal prompt, as though it has been activated.

I have to activate, then deactivate, then reactivate, to force this to happen, using the following commands:

`source activate envname`

`source deactivate`

`source activate envname`

Any clue as to why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: The command for conda >= 4.4 is `conda activate <env-name>`. Can you try that command?

Comment: ^ I can try that command

Comment: I'll say this again as I seem to have to on all my posts. Why downvote?? If there was something I'm missing from this post could you at least just let me know? I'd be happy to add it! I tried to provide all the information I could. It just seems so unnecessary to do that.

Comment: I didn't downvote your post here, but on this post, I'd suspect the reason for the downvote is that your question is not very specific and is nearly impossible for anyone to reproduce on their own computer to try to test solutions. The key word is **Sometimes** - if this is an intermittent issue, you should try and document when it happens, or try to figure out how to get it to happen consistently, then post that detail. This post would also be improved by adding the sequence of commands that you use to determine that a problem has occurred. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks! I tried to add a bit more, but I'm not really sure what else I could have said. I took away the "sometimes" as the error is now consistent. I mean, this is actually all that I know about this problem. I gave which kind of anaconda i'm using and the system i'm running on.  What else would be helpful here?

Comment: With what you have here, it seems like a pretty good question. Did you try the `conda activate` command I suggested?

Comment: "CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'."

Comment: It has instructions for how to do this, but i'm in crunch time at school, so i'll have to come back to it.