# Conda does not set paths when activating environment

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda, tmux

When starting a new shell, the PATH environment variable is not configured
properly. The directories `anaconda3/bin` or `miniconda3/bin` are at second
position only, not at first position in the PATH variable. This can be
resolved by `conda deactivate` and activating it again.

This question was asked several times already (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093121/conda-fails-to-set-up-paths-when-activating-an-environment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246350/conda-activate-not-working))
but the existing questions are either very old or concentrate on the use of
`source activate env-name`. All in all, I found no answer that resolves my
problem.

When I start a new shell, the base environment is activated. The relevant
snippet from my `.bashrc` reads like this:

```sh
condaexe="/home/$USER/.miniconda3/bin/conda"
condash="/home/$USER/.miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
__conda_setup="$($condaexe 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
# shellcheck disable=SC2181
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
elif [[ -f "$condash" ]]
then
    source "$condash"
fi
unset __conda_setup condaexe condash
```

Then, the PATH variables are defined as follows:

```sh
(base)$ echo $PATH
/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.miniconda3/bin:/home/user/.miniconda3/condabin:/home/user/workspace/my-project/:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(base)$ conda deactivate && echo $PATH
/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.miniconda3/condabin:/home/user/workspace/my-project/:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ conda activate base && echo $PATH
/home/user/.miniconda3/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.miniconda3/condabin:/home/user/workspace/my-project/:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(base)$
```

Note that `/home/user/.local/bin` is contained twice; once before and once
after the Miniconda3 directories.

I tried to debug the problem by appending the following snippet to `.bashrc`:

```sh
echo $CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
echo $PATH
```

This yields

```
(base)
/home/user/.miniconda3/bin:/home/user/.miniconda3/condabin:/home/user/workspace/my-project:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

which would be perfectly fine but, somehow, is modified **after** `.bashrc`.
Note that here `/home/user/.local/bin` is contained only once.

What goes on here? How can I setup Bash/Conda to get a properly defined PATH
environment variable?

Comment: How are you launching shell - is there perhaps a `.bash_profile` also being loaded (e.g., `bash -l`)? What does `conda init -vv -d` output? Does it propose making further changes to `.bashrc`? Also, did you code that section in .bashrc yourself? - it doesn't match the standard template I've seen before. The output of `conda info` could be useful to include.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your mention of `.bash_profile` brought me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three components I missed in the original question which are key to the solution.

First, I run all my shells inside TMux. Second, TMux sources the `.profile`. Third, in `.profile` some local directories like the aformentioned `~/.local/bin` are blindly prepended to the PATH.

Taken this altogether all the weird behaviour above makes sense. Especially that PATH is correct at the end of `~/.bashrc` but not in the shell is obvious now; it got modified in between by `~/.profile`.

There are three solutions for this:

1. deactivating and activating conda manually (temporary workaround)
2. being more picky about which shells are started inside TMux (very unhandy)
3. commenting out the manipulations of PATH in `~/.profile`

It seems as if one cannot configure TMux to source only `~/.bashrc` ([reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652126/bashrc-profile-is-not-loaded-on-new-tmux-session-or-window-why#9652210), [reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464543/can-one-configure-tmux-to-load-bashrc-instead-of-bash-profile)), albeit some workarounds exist here too.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the Bash init files. By default, `~/.bashrc` is used in an **interactive, non-login** shell. It won't be sourced in a login shell. Tmux uses a **login shell** by default. Hence, shells started by tmux skip `~/.bashrc`.

> `default-command` shell-command
>
> The default is an empty string, **which instructs tmux to create a login shell** using the value of the `default-shell` option.

Init files for Bash,

1. login mode:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
2. **interactive** **non-login**:

   1. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   2. `~/.bashrc`
3. non-interactive:

   1. source file in `$BASH_ENV`

The weird interactive, non-login loading requirement confuses people in other situations as well. The **best solution** is to change the loading requirement of `~/.bashrc` as **interactive only**, which is exactly what some distros, like Ubuntu, are doing.

```
# write content below into ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This should be the solution you desire. And I recommend every Bash user setup this in the profile.

References

- [Unix Shell Initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)
- `man tmux`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post! That give me hint to debug same issue. I think everyone is different situdation but the idea is same: there is a command like `export $PATH` change the path in your `zshrc` or `.bashrc` which will affect the computer to find the path you want.